# asyncio + asyncpg + pandas: obtain pandas.df with async selects from db - ERROR

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, asyncpg

Edited my code - NOW it WORKS
I'm trying to obtain some date from my Postgres db through asyncpg connection pool asynchronously.
Basically my db contain about 100 different tables (per city) and i'm trying to gather all the data in one frame as fast as it possible.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import asyncpg
    import asyncio
    from time import time


    def make_t():
        lst = []
        # iterator for sql tuple
        for i in ['a',
                  'b',
                  'c']:
            i1 = i
            sql = """
    SELECT
    '%s' as city,
    MAX(starttime) AS max_ts
    FROM
    "table_%s"
    """
            lst.append(sql % (i, i1))
        return tuple(lst)


    async def get_data(pool, sql):
        start = time()
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
           stmt = await conn.prepare(sql)
           columns = [a.name for a in stmt.get_attributes()]
           data = await stmt.fetch()
           print(f'Exec time: {time() - start}')
           return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)


    async def main():
        dsn = 'postgres://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/my_base'
        cT = ['city', 'max_ts']
        sqls = make_t()
        pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=dsn, max_size=50)
        start = time()
        tasks = []

        for sql in sqls:
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(get_data(pool, sql)))

        tasks = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cT)
        for task in tasks:
            # form df from corutine results
            df = df.append(task.result())

        print(f'total exec time: {time() - start} secs')
        print('exiting main')
        return df


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    df = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()

    print('exiting program')
```

Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Gets me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "", line 319, in 
>             File "/Users/fixx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line
>   468, in run_until_complete
>           return future.result()
>             File "", line 308, in main
>             File "/Users/fixx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 594, in gather
>           for arg in set(coros_or_futures):
>               TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I cant figure out, why? My sqls in tuple!

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio.gather` accepts coroutines as individual arguments, and you are sending it a list of tasks. You have to use the `*` operator to call `gather` correctly:

```
        tasks = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also spotted that. Now it throws another ERROR i can't google:
<code>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 321, in <module>
    File "*/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in              run_until_complete
    return future.result()
    File "<string>", line 309, in main
    File "<string>", line 290, in get_data
    AttributeError: __aexit__
</code>

Comment: @Fixx Probably the return value of `conn.cursor()` is not a context manager usable in the `async with` statement.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem! Thanks!!! I've changed my def a bit, so that it returns df, suitable for context manager!